# Write data received from com port to .txt file (raspbian)

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, port, raspbian

Basically I had a com port connected to raspberry pi and I am trying to append the data received into a .txt file. So far I'm only successful in opening the file.. How should I edit the existing code to make it able to "save" the data into the open file?

I did also tried editing it by:

```
FILE *f;
f = fopen("try.txt", "a");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
    }

int r;        
char buf[255];       
    while( 1 )
    {        
    r = read( fd, buf, 255 );        
    buf[r]=0;        
    fprintf( f, "%s", buf);
    }
fclose(f);
```

but seems like this will stop the data from being received.

Now the existing code is the following:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define SPEED B9600
#define PORT "/dev/ttyUSB0"

int main( )
{      
int fd = open( PORT, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY );        
    if (fd <0) 
    {
    perror(PORT); 
    exit(-1); 
    }        
struct termios options;

bzero(&options, sizeof(options));        
options.c_cflag = SPEED | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD | IGNPAR;        
tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);        
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

FILE *f;
f = fopen("try.txt", "a");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
    }

int r;        
char buf[255];       
    while( 1 )
    {        
    r = read( fd, buf, 255 );        
    buf[r]=0;        
    printf( "%s", buf);
    }
}
```

New to raspbian etc.. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Sorry... format..? meaning to?

Comment: Format or ident means putting blank space at the beginning of each line in order to represent the blocks of your program so it is more readable. Look at _your_ program and look at the examples in your C textbook, you will notice the difference

Comment: Is your input line oriented text, or can it contain binary data ? And how do you intend to go out of your `while(1)` loop (break could loose data)?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you are trying to print a string, and your buffer is not formatted correctly: a string ends with a '\0', and the printf will be looking for that.

You can either read 254 characters and manually add the '\0' as the last character or use some other mechanism (cout for example).

But even that is more messy. There is a more difficult to implement, but much more elegant solution:

1. Read is a blocking function; i.e it will block until you read the expected amount of data. You can avoid this by configuring the port you are reading from to be non blocking (see O_NONBLOCK)
2. Use select with a timeout, to know when data becomes available
3. When data is available, read it like so:

   nr_bytes = read( fd, buf, 255 );

   Yes it's the same read you were using only this time it return once it reads the available data instead of waiting for all 255 bytes. So you have  just read `nr_bytes` bytes, which you can write to your file.
4. Repeat...

Hope this helps!